# Want to load same Javascript file in both client-side and server-side scripts on MEAN-stack app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mean-stack

I developed a MEAN-stack web app generated by [angular-fullstack](https://github.com/DaftMonk/generator-angular-fullstack).  I wrote a file, date.js, that appends some helpers to Date.prototype.  I want to load this file to access these helpers both on the server (in the API handlers) and on the client.

Server-side code can load anything with "require([path/to/...]module-name)" whereas client side code gets loaded explicitly by

```
<java src="path/to/my-code.js"></java>
```

tags in the page.

My goal is to place data.js (and other common utilities) in a place where it can be easily accessed from either client-side or server-side code without having to maintain a copy on each.

While developing on my local box I solved this by placing it in my-app/client/assets/js/ where it can be loaded from the index.html page, and load it from server-side scripts with

`require("path/to/my-app.../client/assets/js/my-code.js")`.

That works fine on my local box but wreaks havoc when I try to deploy it to Heroku.  Heroku renames my-app/client as "public" so those server-side require() calls no longer work.

There has to be a better way to do this.  Libraries like "lodash" are loaded both as Bower packages and as Node packages.  Do I have to publish my little date.js library as a separate project available to both Bower and npm?

Comment: you could try globbing for the file in the client directory using https://github.com/isaacs/node-glob. not the most elegant solution but it could work!

Comment: have a look at browserify as well.  I had great success with gulp & browserify regarding loading up all the files easily.

Comment: I found a workaround that didn't require this library anymore, but thanks to @gabereal et al. for your comments.